# A script to make a script to write multiple similar files

Tags: python, bash, templates

I am trying to write a script `A` that will take a VHDL file `X` as input and create a script `B` to generate several files similar to `X` but with small differences (eg the initial value of a signal changes). I would like the scripts to take into account white space to keep the look of the original file `X`. I'm trying to do it in Python, but if you have any help for bash that would also help.

Comment: Sounds like you want some kind of template system?

Comment: Yes, a template is a good description of what I am looking for. Are there better languages to use for that?

Comment: Google python template gets plenty: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating has lots of resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash is the best option if you don't want to carry on with dependencies, you can make use of grep, sed, cut or awk available in any nix based system

for every different output file needed do,

Read the input file A line by line.

Evaluate for your own patterns using grep in every line and replace the content of the line if it matches using your "dynamic" values.

append every processed line to a new file and repeat until you have finished all your output files.

The hard thing with this is that you might spend a lot of time if you don't find yourself comfortable using this tools, but isn't harder than any other programming language